# invariant well-ordering on binary words

Tags: set-theory

Let $X$ be the set of all infinite to the right binary words, $X^0$ -- the monoid of all finite binary words. There is a natural action of $X^0$ on $X$, namely the concatenation. Does there exists an invariant well-ordering on the set $X$? I am also interested in the same question for the set $X^\sharp$ of non-periodic words.

Periodic word means non-purely periodic e.g. $111101010101010101010101010...$

Well-ordering is called invariant if for any $a \in X^0$ and $x, y \in X$ $x<y$ implies $ax < ay$.

Of course it is enough to construct such ordering on the equivalence classes under the action ($x \sim y$ iff there exist $a,b \in X^0: ax=by$). The equivalence classes are different for periodic and non-periodic words, this is why the question about $X^\sharp$ is interesting.

P.S. I deeply believe in the axiom of choice :)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $<$ is such a well ordering (either for $X$ or for $X^{\sharp}$). Fix a non periodic $x$. Then for each $\sigma \in X^0$, $\sigma x > x$ otherwise we get an infinite $<$-descending sequence. But then chopping first bit of $x$ gives us something strictly less than $x$. Repeating this gives a $<$-descending sequence which is impossible.

Comment: hm. I don't see how to finilize this approach
the sets $\{\sigma x : \sigma \in X^0\}$ intersect nontrivially. And there is no well-ordering that respects all orders on them, as much as I can see (because each subword is less then a word itself, therefore you can have an order but not a well ordering)

Comment: Pick any $x \in X^{\sharp}$, well order $A_x  = \{\sigma x : \sigma \in X^0\}$. Then pick $y \in X^{\sharp} \backslash A_x$ and well order $A_y$ and put $A_y$ after $A_x$ and so on.

Comment: if $y$ is a subword of $x$ then $A_y \supset A_x$

Comment: If $x \neq y$, how can $y$ be a subword of $x$?

Comment: $x=1y$ for example. it looks like there is something obvious I miss

Comment: Ok, I see a problem. Let me think.

Comment: OK, there is no such well ordering for $X^{\sharp}$. I am editing the answer.

Comment: you are saying that if $x=1y$ and $y \not \in X^\sharp \setminus A_x$. Thet $y=\sigma_x$ and $x$ is periodic.
The fact that $A_x$ is closed under the action of a monoid does not imply that $X^\sharp \setminus X$ is because  $X^0$ is a monoid, not a group

Comment: Oh, thanks. Quite dissapointed with the result, though :)

Comment: Why disappointed?

Comment: I can think of a few nice existence things that can be based on the existance of such order

Comment: Well, we can now prove Riemann hypothesis too based on the existence of such things :P.